# Accessing Location via GPS in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have been trying to get location via gps through the following code. I get the updates when i change the provider to NETWORK_PROVIDER, but i dont receive any data or location when i use GPS_PROVIDER.
I have referred the following tutorials-
http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/12/how-to-get-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android.html
and 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNb_3QKSmMk

```
package app.com.example.android.locationapp;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    TextView lat, longi;
    LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    longi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable location permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        Log.i("MainActivity", "reqLocationUpdates() method called");

    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("MainActivity","onLocation executed");
    lat.setText(location.getLatitude() + "");
    longi.setText(location.getLongitude() + "");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest using FusedLocationProviderApi. It's more accurate and will resolve many things to you. 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Comment: Okay i'll check that too but can you help me find the problem in this code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have fine location permission set.  And make sure you're doing runtime permissions checks.  But most likely your problem is LOS to satellites.  If you're testing indoors, you probably can't get the satelite signal.  Without that, you can't figure out your location and it will never call you.  Go outside to test and see if it works.